# Understanding Index Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition in Wolfram: "A set whose members index (label) members of another set." I was just trying to figure out what **index** and **label** actually mean.

Thank You

Comment: A common example of an index set would be the natural numbers. We usually use the natural numbers to index a sequence of numbers or functions, say $x_n$ or $f_n$ where $n$ is a natural number. We want to use the same letter $x$ to signify that they are all terms of the same sequence, but we want to number, or index, them.

Comment: @danielson Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I$ and $A$ be any set. Let $f : I \rightarrow A$ be a surjective function, which means that for all $a \in A$, there exists an $i \in I$ such that $f(i) = a$.

Then one can say that $f$ is a labeling of $A$ by $I$. $I$ is the index set. For each $a \in A$, an element of $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is a label or index for $a$.